# Swift - tap gesture is not recognized in subView of KeyWindow

Tags: ios, swift

I made a view that used as black overlay by adding itself to keyWindow.
It shows as intended but tap gesture is not triggered.

```
class Menu{
let backView = UIView()
let menuWidth:CGFloat = 150
let menuView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()

init(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        backView.frame = window.frame
        backView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissHandler)))
        backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        backView.alpha = 0

        menuView.frame = CGRect(x: -1*menuWidth, y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: window.frame.height)
    }
}

func show(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        window.addSubview(backView)
        //window.addSubview(menuView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.backView.alpha = 1
            self.menuView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menuWidth, height: window.frame.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func dismissHandler(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.backView.alpha = 0
            self.menuView.frame = CGRect(x: -1*self.menuWidth, y: 0, width: self.menuWidth, height: window.frame.height)
        }){(isSuccess) in
            if(isSuccess){
                self.backView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.menuView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked frame size of window and backview but they are same. Any idea why it is not working?

Solved:
Problem was that I was making its instance in local scope. Thanks matt for providing me the answer.

Comment: Not showing enough code to allow us to implement your code and test it.

Comment: Sorry, i posted the entire class.

Comment: Good but you didn't show how you use the Menu class itself to make anything happen. But that could be where the problem is. For example, suppose you create the Menu class instance but you don't maintain it somehow. Then you might be able to create the overlay, but the Menu instance is gone, so the tap gesture recognizer has no `target` to talk to — your `self` has gone out of existence. But that's just a guess because you are not providing enough information still, do you see? I could be totally wrong. But you are forcing me to _assume_ stuff by not _showing_ what you're doing.

Comment: That was the problem. I am sorry for not providing sufficient information.

Comment: Oooh, cool. :) I'll give that as an answer (because the mistake you're making is one that others might make, so this Q&A could help others).

Comment: Yes, it was stupid mistake. I'll be careful with providing enough information next time. Sorry and thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! I'm very happy it was so easy to figure out in the end. — This is a good example of how you shouldn't leave stuff out when you ask a question, because, after all, the reason you are having a problem might lie in something you're not showing, and you can't know this in advance, because after all that's _why_ you're having a problem, i.e. you don't _know_ where the issue might lie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your original question, you didn't show how you use the Menu class itself to make anything happen. But that could be where the problem is.

For example, suppose you create the Menu class instance but you don't *maintain* it somehow. Then you might be able to create the overlay, but after that, the Menu instance is gone, so the tap gesture recognizer subsequently has no `target` to talk to.

In other words, you've got this tap gesture configuration code:

```
backView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissHandler)))
```

...but when the user taps and the tap gesture recognizer tries to send its message, your `self` has gone out of existence.

Comment: I'm really glad it was so simple to fix in the end!

Comment: Had a similar issue where a custom class handled logic for a view, scope of that custom class was lost in my view controller if not declared as a class property. This was the answer I needed. Also weird that it was working in my playground though.

Comment: this answer saved my day

Comment: @hsing I am amazed you even _found_ this answer! :)